# Python: Unresolved reference 'myvar'

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

I am working on ttkbootstrap but it gives an error like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mkxL.png)

I leave the codes below

```
my_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Click!", bootstyle=SUCCESS, font="Helvetica, 50")
my_label.pack(pady=50)

myvar = 0
def change():
    myvar += 1
    if myvar & 2 == 0:
        my_label.config(text="Selam")
    else:
        my_label.config(text="BB")
```

I tried something but it's not right

Comment: If you don’t declare myvar as global inside your function, it is treated as a local variable. Therefore “myvar += 1” causes an error because the local variable myvar is not initialized.

Comment: `myvar` in `change` function is a local variable, because you assign to it. It is separate from the `myvar` outside the function. If you want to make them the same, you need to add `global myvar` at the beggining of the function to tell Python those are the same variable.

Comment: Typo error missing quotes.  Should be `bootstyle='SUCCESS'`

Comment: Move `myvar = 0` inside function and move the `myvar += 1` at the bottom outside `if/else` block. The output is Selam

Comment: oh, thank you for help. It is good.